# How to put Editable edittext within a listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I use section adapter for the whole listview.Now in this image,there is a edittext which is not editable.I want to make this edittext editable.

[image: I use section adapter for the whole listview.Now in this image,there is a edittext which is not editable.I want to make this edittext editable.]

Comment: Please include xml for the layout. This will help the community to provide better answers.

Comment: Can you show your code without?

Comment: if your edittext is in list then you can refer to [this](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/)

Comment: Thanks Hanry i will,if have time come to Casual Chat Room

Answer (score 9):

Try Adding  **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"**   in the activity holding the 
listview.

This is because i think that EditText's parent view is being recreated.
Preference's getView(View convertView, ViewGroup parent) is being
called with a blank convertView, rebuilding the entire view rather
than reusing the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem before, after searching lot I got one tutorial which was very helpful to solve this issue...please refer it...

http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/

Comment: i have already got this solution,
You are too late,but i appriciate your hard work.

Answer (score 1):

Try and use the following code inside the listview:

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

More info:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability

Answer (score 0):

You should use this for the declaration of the layout of the list item

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fillh_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 </EditText>
```

So you have to check to your xml if `android:editable="false"` has been set and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can go for custom listview, IN normal list view is not possible ,By using custom listview you have two xml file, In one xml, you will have your listview and in another xml you have to specify you edittext.. Thats all..

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what really your question is. If it is that you are not able to edit the EditText which is inside the custom ListView, then you need to add

```
android:focusable="false"
```

for EditText in your custom Layout.